# Finding the change in the value of a function from a point along a vector for a specified distance

Tags: calculus, integration, vectors

I am solving some basic vector calculus questions (new to the field), and one of the questions I found goes like this:

[image: example question]

How do I solve this? I know that the total change can be found by finding $\int_{\bar{a}}^\bar{b} \! \nabla f.\bar{dl}$ , but in this case what are my $\bar{a}$ and $\bar{b}$ vectors, along with $\bar{dl}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the analogous Calculus 1 question: If $f(x)=x^2$, how would you compute the change in the function value from the point $x_0=1$ in the positive x-direction $0.1$ units?  You would find the point $x_1 = 1 + 0.1$, and just compute the difference $\Delta f = |f(x_1)-f(x_0)|$, or more suggestively, $\Delta f = f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)$ where $h=0.1$.

You could also compute the integral $\int _1^{1.1}2xdx\:$, but why not do subtraction rather than integration?

What you are being asked is actually just to compute the value of the function f at the point $Q = (3,0) + 0.1\cdot \hat{\textbf{u}}$ and subtract it from $f(3,0)$.

i.e. $\Delta f = f(P + h\hat{\textbf{u}}) - f(P)$.

P.S. If you did decide to integrate for some reason, P and Q would be your bounds.

Comment: Thanks! This was quite insightful for approaching these kind of questions